# R studio just stops plotting - repeatedly, how to fix

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio, pheatmap

I have a recurring problem where R studio just stops plotting. The code for plots works fine, as the plots are saving to file, but they just stop showing up in the plot pane.

Restarting the whole session seems to fix, but then I have to reload everything and it happens again almost immediately.

Would be grateful for any insight.

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] RColorBrewer_1.1-2  pheatmap_1.0.12     stringr_1.4.0       gplots_3.1.1        viridis_0.5.1      
 [6] viridisLite_0.3.0   VennDiagram_1.6.20  futile.logger_1.4.3 tibble_3.0.5        fuzzyjoin_0.1.6    
[11] ggthemes_4.2.4      tidyr_1.1.2         dplyr_1.0.3         data.table_1.13.6   readr_1.4.0        
[16] ggVennDiagram_0.3   ggrepel_0.9.1       ggplot2_3.3.3       cowplot_1.1.1      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] gtools_3.8.2         tidyselect_1.1.0     purrr_0.3.4          sf_0.9-7             colorspace_2.0-0    
 [6] vctrs_0.3.6          generics_0.1.0       utf8_1.1.4           rlang_0.4.10         e1071_1.7-4         
[11] pillar_1.4.7         glue_1.4.2           withr_2.4.0          DBI_1.1.1            lambda.r_1.2.4      
[16] lifecycle_0.2.0      munsell_0.5.0        gtable_0.3.0         caTools_1.18.1       labeling_0.4.2      
[21] class_7.3-17         fansi_0.4.2          Rcpp_1.0.6           KernSmooth_2.23-17   scales_1.1.1        
[26] classInt_0.4-3       formatR_1.7          farver_2.0.3         gridExtra_2.3        digest_0.6.27       
[31] hms_1.0.0            stringi_1.5.3        cli_2.2.0            tools_4.0.3          bitops_1.0-6        
[36] magrittr_2.0.1       futile.options_1.0.1 crayon_1.3.4         pkgconfig_2.0.3      ellipsis_0.3.1      
[41] assertthat_0.2.1     rstudioapi_0.13      R6_2.5.0             units_0.6-7          compiler_4.0.3
```

Comment: What RStudio version are you using?

Comment: My first troubleshooting step would be to reinstall RStudio, either with the latest stable version or the preview version, and see if the problem still occurs. If so, I'd submit a bug report.

Comment: Just run graphics.off() and then replot.

Comment: I agree with micyo, what do you mean when you say that you save your files in your script. If you use `jpeg()` function, it won't plot in rstudio if I remember it well

Comment: If that's the case, use `ggsave()` instead when using `ggplot2` to create plots.